# GWT tab panel - how to put the tabs on the bottom

Tags: gwt, tabs, tabpanel, gwt-tablayoutpanel

I have been struggling with a problem and searching the web did not yield any result.

Basically I am trying to create in GWT ( plain GWT without ext or smart) a tab panel.

The catch is that I need the tabs to be on the bottom of the panel, not at the top, how they are by default.

Do you have any ideas on how I can achieve this?

Thank you.

Update 1: (To be more clear I have added screenshots)
What is the default -> [default tab position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tzM7q.png)

What I need -> [needed tab position](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gPKeo.png)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10736400/tablayoutpanel-at-the-bottom-of-the-page-in-gwt

Comment: Hi @nerdlyist , thanks for the link. However what I actually want is not to place the whole tab panel at the bottom of the page, but to place the tabs at the bottom of the tab panel. I will update my post with screenshots.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TabPanel` is actually an aggregate of a [TabBar](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/TabBar.html) and a [DeckPanel](http://www.gwtproject.org/javadoc/latest/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/DeckPanel.html) widgets. You can arrange them as you like. All you have to do is to `addSelectionHandler` (or `addBeforeSelectionHandler`) to the `TabBar` that will `showWidget` (according to selected tab) on the `DeckPanel`.

For example:

```
TabBar tabs = new TabBar();
final DeckPanel deck = new DeckPanel(); 

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    tabs.addTab("Tab " + Integer.toString(i + 1));
    deck.add(new Label("Label " + Integer.toString(i + 1)));
}

tabs.addSelectionHandler(new SelectionHandler<Integer>() {
    @Override
    public void onSelection(SelectionEvent<Integer> event) {
        deck.showWidget(event.getSelectedItem());
    }
});

VerticalPanel vPanel = new VerticalPanel();
vPanel.add(deck);
vPanel.add(tabs);

tabs.selectTab(0);
```

Comment: thank you for the response. It works. For the future I will add some styling and maybe do this with UiBinder. Certainly a great answer.